# Row of Listview hidden

Tags: android, listview, android-framelayout

i need to create a listview into a framelayout.

This is my code:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_info"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listViewEjercicios"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_ejercicios"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabCrearEntrenamiento"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/layout_ejercicios"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

It works almost fine but the first row always is hidden by the toolbar. 
The rest rows look good.

I try to add padding_top in the row_layout.xml, but is no a solution.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="21sp" >
</TextView>
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/holo_light_background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_ejercicios"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_ejercicios"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_info"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/bar"/>


     <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabCrearEntrenamiento"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/layout_ejercicios"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
   </FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. You give me an idea. I put the toolbar out of the framelayout only and it works. I dont use coordinator layout and appbarlayout because i have more layouts and parents into my xml. So thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. You used a FrameLayout. Yes, all views overlap in a FrameLayout. Use a LinearLayout because you have set `orientation="vertical"`
2. You should put Toolbar above other things
3. CoordinatorLayout would be better

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_ejercicios"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Some other layout behind the Action Button -->
    <include layout="@layout/list_view"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabCrearEntrenamiento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: 1. If i use LinearLayout instead FrameLayout my FAB disapear

Comment: 2. I put toolbar above framelayout and it works. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you should use FrameLayout at all

Comment: And What you recommended me?

Comment: Point 3. CoordinatorLayout. You just want a ListView, right? So you don't need to surround that in a FrameLayout, I don't think. Just add the ListView directly